# Magento tries to load file from src folder

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8, database, module

> Error in file:
>   "/var/www/test/magento_custom/app/code/community/Fabric/Material/data/fabric_material_setup/data-install-1.0.0.0.1.php"
>   -Warning: include(/var/www/test/magento_custom/includes/src/Fabric_Material_Model_Material.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in
>   /var/www/test/magento_custom/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line
>   94

I am having this issue, when install custom module. What would be the issue?

sql setup file.

```
$installer = $this;

/**
 * Creating table fabric_news
 */
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('fabric_material/material'))
    ->addColumn('news_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'unsigned' => true,
        'identity' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'primary'  => true,
    ), 'Entity id')
    ->addColumn('title', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, array(
        'nullable' => true,
    ), 'Title')
    ->addColumn('author', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 63, array(
        'nullable' => true,
        'default'  => null,
    ), 'Author')
    ->addColumn('content', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, '2M', array(
        'nullable' => true,
        'default'  => null,
    ), 'Content')
    ->addColumn('image', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, null, array(
        'nullable' => true,
        'default'  => null,
    ), 'News image media path')
    ->addColumn('published_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATE, null, array(
        'nullable' => true,
        'default'  => null,
    ), 'World publish date')
    ->addColumn('created_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
        'nullable' => true,
        'default'  => null,
    ), 'Creation Time')
    ->addIndex($installer->getIdxName(
            $installer->getTable('fabric_material/material'),
            array('published_at'),
            Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_INDEX
        ),
        array('published_at'),
        array('type' => Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_INDEX)
    )
    ->setComment('Material item');

$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
```

data setup file.

```
$installer = $this;

/**
 * @var $model Fabric_News_Model_News
 */
$model = Mage::getModel('fabric_material/material');

// Set up data rows
$dataRows = array(
    array(
        'title'          => 'Cotton',
        'content'        => '<p>Suitable for very sunny climate</p>',
        'created_at'=>'2015-02-13 13:14:47'
    ),
     array(
        'title'          => 'Synthetic',
        'content'        => '<p>Suitable for very sunny climate</p>',
        'created_at'=>'2015-02-13 13:14:47'
    )
);
// Generate news items
foreach ($dataRows as $data) {
    $model->setData($data)->setOrigData()->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer from below link. The Problem is that I enabled compilation in

> **System->Tool->compilation.**

That is why, Magento duplicate everything in modules into src. Because of this, Errors have come.

[Answer Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588912/magento-modules-duplicated-into-include-src)

Answer (score 0):

Go to this file

```
includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php
```

Go to line 94.
There is the problem.

Comment: Hi @Prashanta Fabric_Material_Model_Material.php this placed in model folder but it loaded from magento include/src.how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In your setup file, you have this code

```
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('fabric_material/material'))
    ...
```

Here `$installer->getTable('fabric_material/material')` is actually trying to get your model file.

Here Magento is generating your model class name as `Fabric_Material_Model_Material` and then looking for it through a bunch of directories and couldnt find that file any where. That is what the error says.

Fix is simple. You need to define `Material` entity inside your custom module `Fabric_Material`. (I hope such module does exist !) In fact, without having a model, you cant do any sort of database operation.

If you are followed magento best practices and conventions, then you need to define this file

File : `app/code/local/Fabric/Material/Model/Material.php`

```
<?php
class Fabric_Material_Model_Material extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
     protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('fabric_material/material');
    }
}
```

Similarly you may need to setup a model resource for your module. Because you are dealing with database operations. So my advice is go through **[Magento Models and ORM Basics](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics)** and make a good understanding and then proceed